# SendMessage to simulate right-click crashes the target app

Tags: c#, winapi, automation, crash

I'm writing a C# automation tool.

Since Microsoft UI Automation doesn't provide any way of simulating right-clicks or raising context menus, I'm using `SendMessage` to do this instead. I'd rather not use `SendInput` because I don't want to have to grab focus.

When I call `SendMessage`, however, it crashes the target app.

Here's my code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public void RightClick<T>(T element) where T: AutomationElementWrapper
    {
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008; /* right button down */
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010; /* right button up */

        var point = element.Element.GetClickablePoint();
        var processId = element.Element.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty);
        var window = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(
            TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty,
                                  processId));
        var handle = window.Current.NativeWindowHandle;

        var x = point.X;
        var y = point.Y;

        var value = ((int)x)<<16 + (int)y;

        SendMessage(new IntPtr(handle), MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(value));
        SendMessage(new IntPtr(handle), MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(value));
    }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more: "I'd rather not use SendInput because I don't want to have to grab focus"? - The app that does the SendInput doesn't need to have focus. Or is it that you don't want the right-click itself to have the side-effect of focusing the target app? (BTW, the reason that UIAutomation doesn't have a way to simulate right-click is because it already exists: SendInput!)

Comment: UIAutomation doesn't grab focus. So far, I've managed to automate everything I want in the background. SendInput does grab focus, so I want to find an alternative (SendMessage doesn't). Also, using user32.dll is in no way as clean or easy to use as UIAutomation! One could argue that SendInput is capable of clicking and typing anywhere, so why would we need UIAutomation at all?

Comment: "One could argue that SendInput is capable of clicking and typing anywhere, so why would we need UIAutomation at all?" - Snark answer: because you can't use SendInput to find elements on the screen. UIAutomation does two different classes of things: it lets you discover information about the UI, and perform some types of interactions with it. For the former, it doesn't need to focus the UI, since it's just passively observing. But if you use it to interact with the UI, it will typically focus the target UI - because UI generally expects to have the focus when its being interacted with.

Comment: SendInput is the most reliable way of simulating input: because the input ends up going through exactly the same pathways that it would go through if an end-user did an actual click. When you use SendMessage/PostMessage, you can end up bypassing a bunch of code, so it's not guaranteed to be an exact equivalent. It might work in some or most cases, but fail silently or mysteriously in others. For example, a mouse hook will still work if the input is sent using SendInput, but won't get called if SendMessage is used. (SendMessage also bypasses any processing in the app's GetMessage loop.)

Comment: Right, but it grabs focus, which is what I'm explicitly trying to avoid. UI Automation does not typically focus the target UI, and works on logical rather than physical levels (for instance, a button is pressed regardless of whether it was a mouse-click or an enter key). Am now in touch with someone at Microsoft to try and provide a solution for this.

Comment: Curious, but why are you trying to avoid letting the target app end up with focus? Apps usually get focus when right-clicked; you're working against the windows way of doing things here, so may run into issues. Also; use of SendMessage might be problematic: I'd expect the SendMessage(WM_RBUTTONUP) to block until after the menu is dismissed (not just drawn!), since many apps use TrackPopupMenu to display context menus; it blocks till the menu is done: by the time your thread is free, menu's gone. (Also, x/y params to WM_BUTTON messages should be relative to the HWND, not the screen.)

Comment: I'm writing an automation tool for use in testing. As a dev, I much prefer to be able to run tests in the background while doing things like viewing logging windows, typing emails, etc. - automated tests can take a while to run. If it works with SendMessage and blocks then I can always switch to PostMessage and just wait until the menu appears (already have the functionality to do this) - but at the moment, neither seems to be working. Also tried relative to the HWND but thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Ok, I think I've got enough of the picture now to give a "proper" answer, see below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up your types. You're using `SendMessage`, which takes a window message (which by convention are named `WM_`...), but you're passing it a `MOUSEINPUT.dwFlags` value that's meant for `SendInput` (which are named `MOUSEEVENTF_`...). You're basically passing gibberish.

What your code is actually doing is sending a window message whose numeric value is 8 (which, in window messages, means `WM_KILLFOCUS`), followed by a window message of 0x10 == 16 (`WM_CLOSE`). It's the latter that's likely causing you problems -- you're telling the window to close. I'm not sure why it would crash, but it would certainly exit.

If you're using `SendMessage`, you need to pass it window messages (`WM_`, for example `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_RBUTTONUP`).

Comment: That'll be one of the problems, then. Can you link some decent documentation at all that explains it for those of us who migrated from Java to C#, have never had to do this, and who are following a ton of misleading posts elsewhere?

Comment: Actually, scratch that. This explains it better than anything I've been poring over for the last 24 hours; Microsoft don't know how to write better documentation than this. Thank you!

Comment: Right. It's stopped crashing, which is the first thing I wanted... but now the context menu doesn't appear in the Desktop's descendants yet, even if I manually click it. Bother! Oh, well. Back to the drawing board... but I learnt a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This reply is long enough I'll put it in an answer slot. I think my answer is basically that the question you are asking is based on an incorrect assumption.

The key issue is that while it's fine to run API-type tests in the background on the same desktop that you're working on, it rarely works out well to do the same for UI-based tests.

Your best bet for long-running UI tests are two machines and a keyboard/monitor switch, or use terminal services to run the test app in a session of its own, so it can have its own view of the world (focus, mouse, keyboard state) that won't interfere with the desktop you're working on.

The fundamental issue is that some UI resources - notably the mouse pointer, and keyboard focus - are shared among all apps on the desktop. And many (most? all?) apps assume that when they're being interacted with, they can do as they please with these.

You can sometimes get away with 'lying' to an app and sending it messages that would usually be the end result of input (such as sending WM_LBUTTONDOWN instead of doing sendinput), but if the app ends up looking at the global mouse state, you'll end up with an inconsistency.

For example, an app might respond to WM_LBUTTONDOWN by using the coords passed as parameters. Or it might ignore them and call GetCursorPos instead - and that could lead to really strange behavior if the mouse is really over your email program instead of the app.

Or you might send a WM_LBUTTONDOWN, and the app responds to it by calling some helper function. The helper function uses GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) to check if the mouse button is actually down - notices that it isn't, so bails early.

(Also, sending the end-result message bypasses other stuff that the app might be relying on; if you send keys directly to a window, you'll bypass much of the accelerator and dialog handling code that's usually in the message loop.)

If the app uses SetCapture() - which is very common for things-that-can-be-clicked, such as buttons and the like - it will fail if the app doesn't have focus. You might get lucky and the app will ignore the failure and luck out - or you might not. Menu-type controls often assume that the app has focus, and will dismiss themselves if they notice that focus is actually elsewhere...

If you own the app that's being tested, you might be able to take this into account and write it such that it can be 'tested' in the background: but be aware that it's no longer running in a manner that's consistent with actual user interaction - so arguably it's not a valid user-equivalent test case! - that's up to you to figure out given your test requirements.

Long story short: you might be able to get something to work here in this specific case, but be aware that there's a whole bunch of issues lurking here, and note that this is definitely not considered to be a UI testing best practice!

Comment: Right, so I can use SendInput (and this does work) - I was just trying out SendMessage. I particularly wanted to know why it had crashed, which Joe has answered for me. Thank you for the additional information, though. I'd point out that at least one Enterprise project has been using an early version of this tool on our dev machines for some time, without the kind of difficulties you're talking about - hence my desire to keep that way of doing things for people wanting a ContextMenu too!

Answer (score 0):

What messages exactly do you send, can you give their Windows definition? According to MSDN:

```
#define WM_RBUTTONDOWN                  0x0204
#define WM_RBUTTONUP                    0x0205
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the details of the crash (exception type?  Location?) but my first suspicion is a reentrancy issue.  I would try using PostMessage instead of SendMessage.  SendMessage is synchronous and waits for the message to be processed before returning, so things get executed during its call.  PostMessage just puts the message in the queue and then returns, and the processing takes place afterwards.

Comment: I wanted to use SendMessage instead of PostMessage so that I didn't get the testing thread back until it had happened (otherwise I start clicking on the menu before it appears), and I didn't want to post details of the crash because it would have taken massive effort/learning to get them (happening in another process) and StackOverflow = LazyWeb - or at least, it will be for the next person who tries the same thing. Thank you!